# Not able to get the correct path using getsystemdirectory() in 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an application  running under 64bit OS (Windows 7). I was expecting [`GetSystemDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemdirectoryw) to return *"C:\Windows\SysWOW64"*. Instead, it returns *"C:\Windows\system32"*.

How do I get it to return *"C:\Windows\SysWOW64"*?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. _"C:\Windows\system32"_ **is** the physical path of the 64-bit system directory! In contrast, _"C:\Windows\SysWOW64"_ is the physical path of the emulated "system32" directory for 32-bit applications. I know, it sounds confusing, just read up [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector) to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was expecting `GetSystemDirectory` to return *"C:\Windows\SysWOW64"*. Instead, it returns *"C:\Windows\system32"*.

As it should be, because `system32` is the official system folder, even for a 32bit app running on 64bit Windows. In that latter case, any files a 32bit app tries to access in `system32` are **silently redirected** to `SysWOW64` by the WOW64 emulator.  You don't need to do anything special in your code to get that behavior.  So keep using `system32` whether your app is 32bit or 64bit.

If you want to get the path of the `SysWOW64` folder specifically, use `GetSystemWow64Directory()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argv, char* args[])
{
    TCHAR sysDir[MAX_PATH];
    GetSystemWow64Directory(sysDir, MAX_PATH);

    std::cout << sysDir << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

**OUTPUT:**

C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Comment: @Jabberwocky For a start there needs to be some discussion of when this function should be called. For instance, it will fail on a 32 bit OS. Furthermore, there is no error checking. It is also weak in that it uses `TCHAR` rather than `wchar_t`. Whilst clearly `GetSystemWow64Directory` is part of a good answer, this answer is low quality.